# can any one help to me to get variable from jquery and use in php

Tags: php, jquery

i have fllowing select list now when i select producertype onchange i want producerType value from jquery and i want to isset(producertype) with php for role and change the role type respectively as

`<select id="ProducerType" name="ProducerType" style="float:left;">
    <option value="Principal">Principal</option>
    <option value="Producer">Producer</option>
    <option value="SoleProprietor">Sole Proprietor</option>

</select>`

`<select id="Role" name="Role" style="float:left;">
    <option value="">Agent</option>

</select>`

Comment: `$('#ProducerType').change(function(){..../* learn and write code */...});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand the question and the answer is going to be complex.
First you need to add onChange event to your ProducerType selectbox.
Add this at the end of your html:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   // attach event on change
   $('#ProducerType').on('change',function(){
      // call script on server to check if isset() and receive values for Role
      $.get("checkproducer.php?ProducerType="+$('#ProducerType').val(),function(result){
               // here the script on server returned data already
               // update Role selectbox with new values
               $('#Role').html(result)
           })
   })
})
</script>
```

Make sure you have jquery.js loaded as usual.

You will need to create a PHP script on server which handles the check and returns new data for your select input. Like this (save as "checkproducer.php"):

```
<?php
    if ($_GET['ProducerType']=="Principal")
       echo "<option value=1>Principal1</option>"
           ."<option value=2>Principal2</option>";
    if ($_GET['ProducerType']=="Producer")
       echo "<option value=1>Producer1</option>".
           ."<option value=2>Producer2</option>";
    if ($_GET['ProducerType']=="SoleProprietor")
       echo "<option value=1>SoleProprietor1</option>"
           ."<option value=2>SoleProprietor2</option>";

    // etc
?>
```

Comment: thanks Tomas Matejicek for your quick reply but tomas i cannot shot out my issue where i get mistake with my query plz can u help can i mail you my file to figure it problem if than  please let me know your email id @Tomas Matejicek

Comment: Just post it here. Thanks

Comment: Thanks Tomas Matejicek after all i solved the problem @Tomas Matejicek